# Cargar datos MySQLl en Modal Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, angularjs

[image: Tabla Ejemplo]

[image: Modal ejemplo]

Hola, como podría cargar todos los datos de la persona en una ventana modal al hacer clic en el botón que se muestra en la imagen llamado Registrar?

Necesito que al darle clic me cargue todos los datos, los cuales están en una base de datos en MySQL.

Se que se puede con AJAX pero la verdad no tengo conocimiento en tal, si me pueden proporcionar información para resolver mi problema seria de gran ayuda.

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Se me ocurre que puedes hacer un llamado por ajax a PHP indicandole el ID del registro. Con ello en PHP haces la consulta y retornas el registro devolviendoselo al front para que lo muestre por pantalla

Comment: podrías proporcionarme algún ejemplo?

Comment: en realidad no. pues este espacio es para poder responder preguntas sobre problemas de programación y eso escapa a un real problema. https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_Overflow. Espero que con el primer comentario pueda orientarte a lo que deseas hacer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$.ajax({
              dataType : 'json',
              type : 'POST',
              url : 'consulta_datos.php',
              data :{id_principal},
              async:true,
              cache:false,
              success : function(response){
                 var id=response.id;
                 var identificacion=response.identi;
                 var nombre_completo=response.nom_compl;
                 $("#id").val(id);
                 $("#identificacion").val(identificacion);
                 $("#nombre_completo").val(nombre_completo);

              },
              error : function(error) {
                console.log(error);
              }
          });
```

Bueno te recomiendo que uses jQuery para hacer tu Ajax que te devuelva los datos de la consulta, cuando creas tu tabla en el botón que abre tu modal, manda una función que vas a hacer en un javascript en esta función que hagas vas a mandarle el parámetro que me imagino es el id de tu tabla haces tu consulta y lo metes en un JSON desde PHP, y del lado de JavaScript lo recibes lo parseas y con Jquery mandas los valores a los input que corresponden, el código anterior es un breve ejemplo de como podrias empezar.

Comment: excelente, que función o dato tendria que ponerle al input <input type="submit" class="btn btn-login" value="Registrar"></td> pára que se cumpla o ejecute la acción ajax

Comment: la funcion onClick de javascript para que cuando den click se dispare tu función del ajax algo asi onClick=funcion(id)